# Google apps script not returning data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I have a Google Apps Script pulling data from a Google Sheet, which gets data via GoogleFinance, (image attached) the price difference "=GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "change")" works fine, but the close price which is called via "=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE((A3), "close", F2),2,2)" just returns #REF!

[screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHdjj.png)

I have tried the getValue and getDisplayValue, but this makes no difference

```
for(var i = 2; i < 72; i++) {
   var thePrice = sheet.getRange('B' + i).getValue();
   var sharename = sheet.getRange('D'+ i).getValue();
   var theDifference = sheet.getRange('C'+ i).getValue();
}
```

Comment: Is the #REF! returned in the sheet or in your code?

Comment: Hi Jason, in the code, the sheet displays what I'd expect, but reading the reply below it seems GoogleFinance historical data is no longer accessible outside of Sheets, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> **Historical** GOOGLEFINANCE data no longer accessible outside of Google
>   Sheet. If you have a spreadsheet with historical data generated from the GOOGLEFINANCE function and you try to download it or access it via Apps Script or an API, the corresponding cells will show #N/A.

For more info: [G Suite update Blog](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/09/historical-googlefinance-data-no-longer.html)

Also, it has been raised in the [App Script issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765021) and the response from Google is "**Won't Fix (Intended behavior)**"